# Login page with a drop down option using python

Tags: javascript, python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am learning python/flask and came across an issue, I have a login page which has login and password input, and I am adding a drop down for state e.g. NY,IN,CA etc. each state has a PostgreSQL DB associated, now when someone login, and select NY or KY and submit. It should select NY/KY associated DB and then go to the next page for displaying the records from the table. The Javsscript associated with the login page is working fine and returning the state ID.

All the db. connection string associated to NY, IN etc. are initialized in the app.config

I tried:

In app.py

I didn’t add, in the "**main**" the below lines

```
engine = create_engine(config['postgres_uri_NY'], use_batch_mode=True)
database = SQLAlchemy(app, session_options={'bind': engine})
```

instead I initialized in the “def login” because when a user login, it should connect to the respective DB

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST','GET'])
@raise_backend_exception('Unable to log in')
def login():
    if request.json['password'] == app.config['webapp_password'] \
        and request.json['username'] == app.config['webapp_username']:
        session['logged_in'] = True
        session['username'] = request.json['username']

     if request.json['state']  == 'NY':
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = config['postgres_uri_NY']
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
        engine = create_engine(config['postgres_uri_NY'], use_batch_mode=True)
        database = SQLAlchemy(app, session_options={'bind': engine}) 
     elif request.json['state']  == 'IN':
        … so on..

return is_logged_in()
```

My question is, is this the correct method of doing or is there a better approach. Btw this didn’t work, when first time e.g. NY is selected and the associated DB shows up, then when I login again, the DB was not available.

Any idea what could be the problem.